# Array List & Conditional Statement for specific user Input

Tags: java, arraylist, conditional-statements

I'm very new to Java, and I'm currently working on an assignment in which I create an array list to store the day of the week and daily temperature input from a user. I am having difficulty creating a conditional statement that will print a table of the days+temperatures entered, along with the average temperature if the user inputs the word "week". I have been able to get all of this information to print, however it is the conditional statement I am struggling with.

I have tried using if-else, and do-while loops to create the condition however I continue to either get errors, or for example with the code I have below nothing will happen if "week" is entered. I have been using "days.equals" but I believe this is where I may have gone wrong.

```
   ArrayList<String> days = new ArrayList<String>(); 
   ArrayList<Double> temp = new ArrayList<Double>(); 

   days.add("Monday");
   days.add("Tuesday");
   days.add("Wednesday");
   days.add("Thursday");
   days.add("Friday");
   days.add("Saturday");
   days.add("Sunday");

  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for Monday through 
  Sunday below.\n" );

  for (int i = 0;i < 7; i++) { // Loop 7 times for each day of the week

     System.out.print("Enter day of week: ");

     days.add(scnr.next());

     System.out.print("Enter temperature: ");

     temp.add(scnr.nextDouble());

  }

  System.out.println("-----------------------------");
  System.out.println("Day\t" + "\tTemperature");
  System.out.println("-----------------------------");

  for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

     System.out.println(days.get(i));
     System.out.print("\t" + "\t");
     System.out.println(temp.get(i));

  }
  double sum = 0.0;

  for ( int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
      sum += temp.get(i);

  }
  double average = (double) sum / temp.size();

  do { 
      System.out.println("\n" + "Average temperature = " + average);
  }
  while(days.equals("Week"));

  }  

  }
```

I'd like the program to output the following when the user inputs the word "week".

```
-----------------------
Day         Temperature
-----------------------
Monday      90.0

Tuesday     94.0

Wednesday   89.0

Thursday    84.0

Friday      82.0

Saturday    85.0

Sunday      88.0

Average temperature = 87.42857142857143
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface in your assignment? If yes, I suggest using `Map<String, List<Double>>`. The key is the day of the week and the value is the list of temperatures for that day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, then what you need to do is wait for user input after you get the temperature for the days, check if the value is "week" and only then print your values.
Something along the following lines should work.

```
ArrayList<String> days = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayList<Double> temp = new ArrayList<Double>(); 

days.add("Monday");
days.add("Tuesday");
days.add("Wednesday");
days.add("Thursday");
days.add("Friday");
days.add("Saturday");
days.add("Sunday");

Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for Monday through 
  Sunday below.\n" );

for (int i = 0;i < 7; i++) { // Loop 7 times for each day of the week
   System.out.print("Enter day of week: ");
   days.add(scnr.next());
   System.out.print("Enter temperature: ");
   temp.add(scnr.nextDouble());
}

// You ask for user input here
System.out.print("Enter 'week' here to see temperature details: ");
String userChoice = scnr.next();

while ("week".equalsIgnoreCase(userChoice)) {

  System.out.println("-----------------------------");
  System.out.println("Day\t" + "\tTemperature");
  System.out.println("-----------------------------");

  for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

     System.out.println(days.get(i));
     System.out.print("\t" + "\t");
     System.out.println(temp.get(i));

  }
  double sum = 0.0;

  for ( int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
      sum += temp.get(i);
  }
  double average = (double) sum / temp.size();
  System.out.println("\n" + "Average temperature = " + average);

  //Ask user if he'd like to see the information again.
  System.out.print("Enter 'week' here to see temperature details again: ");
  userChoice = scnr.next();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped! I'll be going back over my course material to be sure I understand where I went wrong. Really, thank you again !